# How to sync Azure storage accounts on different Azure regions?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-automation, azcopy, azure-runbook

Since our RA-GZRS enabled Azure storage can't write to the secondary region when primary is down, thought of having another standby Azure storage to do the writes continuously.

The question is once the main storage account comes back, how sync the updates back to the main from standby? Can we write runbook using AzCopy.exe? Any other better Azure service/solution to accomplish sync process using AzCopy.exe/other as a background service?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the outage isn't severe enough that Microsoft doesn't failover to the secondary region.  You can initiate the failover yourself, and then you would be able to write to the secondary region.  This is essentially a DNS change which makes the secondary endpoint become the primary endpoint.  Once the primary region becomes available again, you can change the storage account to geo-redundant storage, and then if required, repeat the failover.

See [Initiate storage account failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal) and [Storage account failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance) for more details.

Comment: As per the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal#important-implications-of-account-failover) , "failover after initiation can vary though typically less than one hour". Considering the duration/delay involved in failover process, during primary region down choosing to fail over to the secondary region to overcome the write limitation of RA-GZRS is not suitable for production workload